# Unitary operators converging weakly to zero: density question

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $U:H\to H$ is a unitary operator on the real Hilbert space $H$. This means $U^*U=UU^* = I$.

Suppose that $U^n$ converges weakly to zero. That means $\langle x,U^ny \rangle \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, for all $x,y\in H$.

I want to know whether or not the set $\{x \in H: \langle x, U^nx \rangle=0$ for some $n \in \Bbb N\}$ is a dense subset of $H$.

I believe this is true but I am not entirely certain that my proof is a good one. Basically I complexify and use the spectral theorem for normal operators. Then (I think) the question basically asks if for any $(0,2\pi)$-valued measurable function $\theta$ defined on some measure space $(X,\mathcal M, \mu)$ such that $\int_X f(x)g(x)\cos(n\theta(x))dx\to 0$ for all $f,g \in L^2(\mu)$, does there exist a dense set of $f\in L^2(\mu)$ such that $\int_X f(x)^2\cos(n\theta(x))dx= 0$ for some $n$? Tediously I have proved that to be true, but I'm looking for a more direct argument, or a counterexample in case my proof has a hole.

I'm also looking for a reference if someone has seen it in a book or a paper.

Comment: What about U=I?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts The powers of $I$ don’t converge weakly to zero.